# iOS Localization of Server Provided Strings

Tags: ios, localization

I need to figure out what is the standard/best practice for displaying localized UI text in an iOS *from text that is received from a remote source*, such as API driven, server-provided text.  iOS Localization of static text is not a problem and we already have a system for managing that.

It seems to me the right and best thing would be to have the translated text sent by the server and displayed as received on the app, but there are some concerns about doing it this way, such as the app's locale/current language being possibly different than the current settings on the server.  This presents the possibility that there may be a mismatch in dialect or language between what the phone is currently set to and what the server is set to.  Also, we are considering how having the server do this breaks any of the S.O.L.I.D. design principles.

So, it comes to two possibilities.  Either the server provides the translated text or the app does.

We could possibly provide a parameter to the server that would indicate which locale the device is set to (ie "en-us").  I imagine that this would be sent as an HTTP request header parameter.

It has also been suggested that the mobile app provide similar functionality for itself.  This would involve maintaining a data store of some kind (tbd) so that display strings would be given to a facade and translated strings would be returned.  ie: `func translate(uiText: String) -> String`.  Internally, it could determine the user's locale and use that as part of the query needed to select the correct translated text.  Again, the implementation of this would have to be decided, but that's not the problem I'm hoping to find a solution for.

To sum it up, what I really need is to know what is standard practice for translating server provided text that is to be displayed to the user and are there any frameworks out there designed to assist with this requirement (assuming the solution should exist in the mobile app)?

It seems to me that this is functionality best provided by the server.  Also note that we have an Android app that would require similar enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to this question but I do not want to mark it as the accepted answer unless I can get some feedback reinforcing what I have learned.

Most of the research I've done has lead me to what works for Web development, which is similar because it's still development but a much different creature than mobile.  Mobile is compiled, which makes the advantages and disadvantages of where to do the presentation logic balance a little differently.

Some sources said it belongs on the server where it came from.  Some sources said the client should do it.  (I'll post references at the end.)

I opened up a discussion amongst my colleagues on the topic and this is where I found what I think will be our best solution.  (Comments and criticisms are certainly welcome.)

I'll refer to data provided by the server through the API here forth as just "server".

For every string that the server provides that is meant to be displayed in the UI, I need to have some way to define these strings statically in the iOS app.  Ideally I think an enum per display string would work.  I can wrap every string with `NSLocalizedString` in the definition of the enum.  Make the enum a `String` type, and initialize an instance of the enum from the string received from the server.  The enum will return the `NSLocalizedString`.  The iOS Localization system should export all of those localized strings, I will receive translations, and they will then exist in the various respective `.strings` files.

EG:

```
enum Emotion: String {
  case happy = "Happy"
  case sad = "Sad"
  case angry = "Angry"
  case joy = "Joy"
  case amused = "Amused"
  case bored = "Bored"
  case undefined = ""

  func translation() -> String {
      switch self {
      case .happy:
          return NSLocalizedString("Happy", comment: "Happy")
      case .sad:
          return NSLocalizedString("Sad", comment: "Sad")
      case .angry:
          return NSLocalizedString("Angry", comment: "Angry")
      case .joy:
          return NSLocalizedString("Joy", comment: "Joy")
      case .amused:
          return NSLocalizedString("Amused", comment: "Amused")
      case .bored:
          return NSLocalizedString("Bored", comment: "Bored")
      default:
          return "--"
      }
    }
  }
```

Implementation:

```
    let thisCameFromTheServer: String? = "Happy"
    let emo = Emotion(rawValue: thisCameFromTheServer ?? "") ?? .undefined
```

**References**

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313726/where-should-i-do-localization-server-side-or-client-side
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373395/api-internationalization
- https://www.appliedis.com/localization-of-xcode-ios-apps-part-1/

Comment: I’m blocked on completing this task. When it is complete, I will mark it as the accepted answer (if things go as I expect).